# Insert a new row based on previous or next time values

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert a new row based on the timeline of my data so that there is no gap within a chunk of time. For example, my current table looks like this:

```
 ID          StartDate                  EndDate                 StartTime                  EndTime  
1573  2019-07-17 00:00:00.000   2019-07-17 00:00:00.000  2019-07-17 09:00:00.000  2019-07-17 10:00:00.000 
1573  2019-07-17 00:00:00.000   2019-07-17 00:00:00.000  2019-07-17 10:00:00.000  2019-07-17 11:00:00.000
1573  2019-07-17 00:00:00.000   2019-07-17 00:00:00.000  2019-07-17 11:00:00.000  2019-07-17 11:45:00.000
1573  2019-07-17 00:00:00.000   2019-07-17 00:00:00.000  2019-07-17 12:00:00.000  2019-07-17 13:00:00.000
8679  2019-09-03 00:00:00.000   2019-09-03 00:00:00.000  2019-09-03 09:00:00.000  2019-09-03 10:00:00.000
```

As you can see, there is a 15 min gap between the third and the last rows and I want to insert a new row like this to get rid of the gap and make it continuous.

```
1573  2019-07-17 00:00:00.000   2019-07-17 00:00:00.000  2019-07-17 11:45:00.000  2019-07-17 12:00:00.000
```

So basically, when there is a gap within the same StartDate and EndDate for the same ID, I'd like to insert a new row to eliminate the gap in the timeline.

I tried to do this with LAG/LEAD function but couldn't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD()` to get the next `StartTime` and compare with existing row `EndTime` to determine if there are any missing or gap.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, 
       t.EndTime as StartTime, 
       t.NextStartTime as EndTime
FROM
(
    select *, NextStartTime = LEAD(StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartTime)
    from   yourtable t
) t
WHERE t.EndTime <> t.NextStartTime
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=931dcee517f12b02103ae42d9b80a4e5)